# Need a dependency property to be static in a base class

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, dependency-properties, .net-4.5

I have moved from CLR properties in my WPF application to dependency properties. I have a problem in that the following code is in a base class which I need to access from various other view models. When it was a CLR property it was static but now it isn't, so always returns null in the view models that haven't set it. Is there a way round this?

```
    public Tuple<Guid, string> SelectedEntity
    {
        get { return (Tuple<Guid, string>)GetValue(SelectedEntityProperty); }
        set { SetValue(SelectedEntityProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedEntityProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("SelectedEntity", typeof(Tuple<Guid, string>), typeof(MyViewModelBase), new PropertyMetadata(null));
```

Comment: Why are you using the dependency property in the first place? As far as I know, they're supposed to be used in controls to enable data-binding (e.g. by XAML), view models should stick to implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged` and that's it...

Comment: I was told to do so by my team leader because of benefits down the line.

Comment: Tell your team lead: dependency properties don't make sense in view models. Just implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`. This keeps your view models independent from WPF and you don't need to derive all you VM classes from DependencyObject.

Comment: These are databound to view items across multiple tab controls. If you update in one tab it needs to reflect this in the other tab views.

Comment: No problem, as long as the VM properties are used as *source* properties in (perhaps two-way) bindings. Therefore it is sufficient to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

Comment: Agree with @Clemens, also, doing DPs in ViewModels brings a lot of problems when it comes to MultiThreading.

Comment: As as aside, Tuples are the devil. Create a proper data structure to hold your data.

Comment: @Clemens: Sure they make sense.  I use 'em all the time.  Unless I know the VM is going to be changing most of its properties from another thread, but that's just because INPC calls are automatically marshalled.  I've never seen a practical example of someone using a ViewModel within different platforms (wpf/winforms would be the most likely), as the patterns differ so much (ICommand in a winform? lol).  So what if your VM is linked to WPF?  Its a leaky abstraction.  And OP's team leader is still wrong.